# CSS file not imported in laravel blade view

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I am trying to import a CSS file into one of my Laravel views but it's not being included for some reason.

This is is what I have in my view file:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('style')
<link href="{{asset('public/css/my-css-file.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="content">view content.....</div>
@endsection
```

If I include my css file in layout file it works fine but I want it applied to one view only. Any help please? Thanks.

Comment: What does your layout look like? Does it yield the `style` section?

Comment: I have @section('style') in the head part of the html which includes other css files meant for layout. @yield('content') is in body part of the html.

Answer (score 1):

`@yield('content')` yields the content of `@section('content')` so you need to do the same for your `@section('style')`:

Replace `@section('style')` in your layout file with `@yield('style')`.

Comment: Then the css is applied to the whole layout which I don't want, I want it applied to the view only.

Comment: Huh? How are you supposed to apply styles to a "view" only?  Your view is "inside" the layout. Doesn't make much sense (to me). Adjust the styles to only apply to specific elements from your view.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to aply style in a view or some components, I use to do this:

```
@section('css')
   -- your awesome styles here --
@stop
```

If Your styles code is not too long, maybe You can copy and paste It inside.